# Divisors on hyperelliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be hyperelliptic of genus $g\geq 2$. For any $0< 2k \leq g$, find a degree $2k$ effective divisor $D$ in $X$ such that 
$\dim |D| = k$. Classify all such divisors up to linear equivalence.

By Clifford theorem, if $X$ is not hypereplliptic we have $D$ is either principal or canonical. But what happens in $X$ is hyperelliptic?

Reference: Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces by Rick Miranda, http://www.its.caltech.edu/~pablos/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf.

Comment: What do you know about the degree 2 hyperelliptic divisor $H$? Do you know how to calculate $h^0(lH)$ for $l$ a non-negative integer? Do you know that $(g-1)H=K$?

Comment: @Mohan A degree 2 hyperelliptic divisor H =p+q is unique up to linear equivalence because the double cover of P^1 is unique. h^0(H)=2 and (g-1)H=K because K has degree 2g-2. But I don't know how to calculate h^0(lH). Also are these divisors equivalent for each k? Thanks.

Comment: Since on $\mathbb{P}^1$, degree determines the linear equivalence class of a divisor, the same holds for $lH$ for any $l$, since $H$ is a pull back from the projective line. Let $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$, the map given by the hyperelliptic involution. Can you determine the (rank two) vector bundle $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: @Mohan As a project space |H|={all effective divisors linearly equivalent to H}=PH^0(O(H)), so dim|H|=h^0(O(H))-1.